# Error al enviar y guardar variable de JavaScript a PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Estoy tratando de pasar una variable de JavaScript a PHP y guardarla en mi base de datos. Al momento de mandarla y que se me guarda en la base de datos está se almacena en un campo completamente distinto.

en el código estoy mandando 2 cosas, el número que genero aleatoriamente y una imagen en base64(Que está si me la guarda en la base de datos)

```js
function capture(){

    html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas){

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);

        ajax.open("POST", "save.php", true);

        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

        ajax.send("image=" + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9), "num=" + num);

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function (){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                console.log(this.responseText)
            }
        }
        
    alert('Su número de reclamo es: ' + num );

    });
}
```

Esté es mi php:

```
<?php 

include './config.php';

ini_set('display_errors', '1');


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$image = $_POST["image"];
$num = $_POST['num'];    


$insertar = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO  solicitudes (num, img) VALUES ('$num', 
'$image')");

}
```

?>

Lo que me pasa es que cuando trato de enviarla, está no se me envía, y en uno de mis intentos logré hacer que se me guarde pero se me guardaba en una nueva fila, y lo que necesito es que se guarda el numero y luego la imagen en una misma fila.

Comment: Quizás aunque hay muchos desarrolladores que no están de acuerdo, agregar un campo en tu tabla denominado id_algo y que sea autoincrementable( 1,2,3,4,5,6...n)  , y tu numero aleatorio quedaría dentro del segundo campo y la imagen en el tercero según puedo ver en tu código,  y la insercion que tampoco le veo nada extraño deberia guardar el numero y la imagen correspondiente en la misma fila.  Saludos

Comment: @Cesarin El ide ya lo tengo, y esté se auto incrementa cuando se almacena un nuevo dato

Comment: ok no tengo idea de que pudiera estar pasando, haber si algún otro miembro sabe que podría estar sucediendo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te miras la sintaxis de [XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) verás que solo admite un parámetro, y tu le estas pasando dos, separados por coma.

```
ajax.send("image=" + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9), "num=" + num);
```

Mira de cambiar eso por esto a ver si tienes más suerte:

```
ajax.send("num=" + num + "&image=" + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9));
```

(he cambiado el orden para dejar la cadena en base64 al final).

De este modo estamos concatenandolo todo en una única cadena de texto, es decir, en un solo parámetro, y no en dos. Fíjate también que en el segundo parámetro agrego `&` antes de `image`, pues es la forma de separar los parámetros en este formato.

Tienes un ejemplo de POST en su propia [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#example_post).

Ya nos diras si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono!